# Google Assistant "Error: no such option: --project-id"

Tags: python, google-assistant-sdk, google-assistant, google-assist-api

I wanted to install Google Assistant on Raspberry Pi 3B+. I watched YouTube videos and read the official guide:
https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/embed/run-sample

And the sequence finally came to the test code,

```
googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk --project-id my-dev-project --device-model-id my-model
```

Of course, I wrote my IDs here

first it gave such an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/env/bin/googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk", line 5, in <module>
    from googlesamples.assistant.grpc.pushtotalk import main
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/pushtotalk.py", line 29, in <module>
    from tenacity import retry, stop_after_attempt, retry_if_exception
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 292
    from tenacity.async import AsyncRetrying
```

I solved it with this code

```
pip install -U tenacity
```

But now it gives such error

```
/home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cffi/cparser.py:163: UserWarning: Global variable 'stderr' in cdef(): for consistency with C it should have a storage class specifier (usually 'extern')
  warnings.warn("Global variable '%s' in cdef(): for consistency "
/home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cffi/cparser.py:163: UserWarning: Global variable '__stderrp' in cdef(): for consistency with C it should have a storage class specifier (usually 'extern')
  warnings.warn("Global variable '%s' in cdef(): for consistency "
Error: no such option: --project-id
```

**I can't find what is the problem please help**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use only googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk and solve problem